# Jabref: export a subset in bibtex format?

Tags: bibtex

Jabref supports exporting the selected entries in different formats, but I wonder if it can actually export to bibtex format. It is useful to select some of the references to create a smaller database that contains, for instance, only the references of some topic or the ones you are citing in a specific paper. Is there any option to automatically do that?

Comment: I'd say that question is quite off-topic, unless you are asking about how to *extend* JabRef with that feature ;) Maybe try [tex.se]?

Comment: Ok, I was trying to skip programming it myself. May I ask if anyone knows whether this feature has been already implemented, or stackoverflow is only meant to ask about programming issues?

Answer (score 2):

To export as bib, you shouldn't go to the export menu but instead: File > Save selected as:

[image]